# Why is the combo of Grails and BootStrap v4 Throwing Uncaught TypeErrors?

Tags: javascript, grails, bootstrap-4

I put bootstrap v4 into my grails 2.3.11 app and immediately when viewing a page I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined". The only JS I am including in my layout is from bootstrap so I don't see what the problem is.

Grails Layout page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'mobile.css')}" type="text/css">
        <g:layoutHead/>
<%--        <g:javascript library="application"/>       --%>

        <r:layoutResources />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-feJI7QwhOS+hwpX2zkaeJQjeiwlhOP+SdQDqhgvvo1DsjtiSQByFdThsxO669S2D" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grailsLogo" role="banner"><a href="http://grails.org"><img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'grails_logo.png')}" alt="Grails"/></a></div>
        <g:layoutBody/>
        <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
        <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </body>
</html>
```

Errors I get in Chrome Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:68
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ util.js:68
(anonymous) @ util.js:10
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
util.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:68
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
```

Comment: Bootstrap needs jquery ;)

Comment: Ah. Apparently when I went to the Bootstrap CDN, it did not include jQuery. Well thanks. If you want to post an official answer you can so I can accept it.

Comment: Nah it's okay i'll earn my 3k with legit questions and answers, glad that it helped :)